# Access specific version of featureClass (Table) through SOE

Tags: arcobjects, server-object-extension

I am new to ArcObject and SOE.

The task I am trying to accomplish is:

1. Find the specific version of a table
2. Copy the table (to a new table) that the non-soe user can access that version of the table.

Any suggestions with which direction I should go?

Comment: This is an application for a multiversion view, not an SOE